# Google sheets script apps script is not functioning as intended and is always returning "No Matching Data Found"

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-apps-script

Basically I have this spreadsheet and I've created a tab called 'hidden' where im importing cells from another spreadsheet and in my tab called '1st Set' I want to search the tab 'hidden' for any cell values/strings equal to B5 from the '1st Set' tab, and if there is a value equivalent i want to move down 4 cells and copy and paste the 16 cells all from the same column into the range B6:B21 on '1st Set' tab

This is the formula I've tried but it only returns 'No Matching Data Found' even when there is matching data can someone please point our the errors I've made or any possible solutions, thank you.

```
function copyDataIfMatch() {
  // Get the active spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  // Get the target sheet by name
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("1st Set");
  
  // Get the value in cell B5 of the target sheet
  var targetValue = targetSheet.getRange("B5").getValue();
  
  // Get the source sheet by name
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("hidden");
  
  // Get the data range from the source sheet
  var sourceData = sourceSheet.getRange("B4:AD123").getValues(); // Adjust the range as needed
  
  // Iterate through each row in the source data
  for (var i = 0; i < sourceData.length; i++) {
    // Check if the value in the first column of the current row matches the target value
    if (sourceData[i][0] == targetValue) {
      // If there is a match, copy the 16-cell range starting from the matched row in the source sheet
      
      // Get the 16-cell range to copy from the source sheet
      var columnToCopy = sourceSheet.getRange(i + 4, 2, 16, 1).getValues(); // Adjust the starting row and column as needed
      
      // Specify the target range in the target sheet where the copied data will be pasted
      var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange("B6:B21"); // Adjust this if you want the copied range to be placed elsewhere
      
      // Copy the data from the source range to the target range
      targetRange.setValues(columnToCopy);
      
      // Return a success message
      return "Data copied successfully!";
    }
  }
  
  // If no matching data is found, return a message indicating so
  return "No matching data found.";
}
```

Comment: What are the values of `targetValue` and `sourceData[i][0]`?  If they are dates the date and time may not match.  Plus this looks suspicious `var columnToCopy = sourceSheet.getRange(4, i + 2, 120, 1).getValues();`.  Don't you mean `var columnToCopy = sourceSheet.getRange( i+4, 2, 16, 1).getValues();` to match "B6:B21".

Comment: I've edited the formula to have many more notes and made the var columnToCopy change

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
function copyDataIfMatch() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var tsh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var tv = tsh.getRange("B5").getValue();
  var ssh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  var svs = ssh.getRange("A2:Z26").getValues(); 
  for (var i = 0; i < svs.length; i++) {
    if (svs[i][0] == tv) {
      var ovs = ssh.getRange(i + 2, 2, 16).getValues(); 
      var targetRange = tsh.getRange("B6:B21"); 
      targetRange.setValues(ovs);
      return "Data copied successfully!";
    }
  }
  return "No matching data found.";
}
```

Sheet0:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N | O | P | Q | R | S | T | U | V | W | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 | COL11 | COL12 | COL13 | COL14 | COL15 | COL16 | COL17 | COL18 | COL19 | COL20 | COL21 | COL22 | COL23 | COL24 | COL25 | COL26 |
| 2 | A2 | B2 | C2 | D2 | E2 | F2 | G2 | H2 | I2 | J2 | K2 | L2 | M2 | N2 | O2 | P2 | Q2 | R2 | S2 | T2 | U2 | V2 | W2 | X2 | Y2 | Z2 |
| 3 | A3 | B3 | C3 | D3 | E3 | F3 | G3 | H3 | I3 | J3 | K3 | L3 | M3 | N3 | O3 | P3 | Q3 | R3 | S3 | T3 | U3 | V3 | W3 | X3 | Y3 | Z3 |
| 4 | A4 | B4 | C4 | D4 | E4 | F4 | G4 | H4 | I4 | J4 | K4 | L4 | M4 | N4 | O4 | P4 | Q4 | R4 | S4 | T4 | U4 | V4 | W4 | X4 | Y4 | Z4 |
| 5 | A5 | B5 | C5 | D5 | E5 | F5 | G5 | H5 | I5 | J5 | K5 | L5 | M5 | N5 | O5 | P5 | Q5 | R5 | S5 | T5 | U5 | V5 | W5 | X5 | Y5 | Z5 |
| 6 | A6 | B6 | C6 | D6 | E6 | F6 | G6 | H6 | I6 | J6 | K6 | L6 | M6 | N6 | O6 | P6 | Q6 | R6 | S6 | T6 | U6 | V6 | W6 | X6 | Y6 | Z6 |
| 7 | A7 | B7 | C7 | D7 | E7 | F7 | G7 | H7 | I7 | J7 | K7 | L7 | M7 | N7 | O7 | P7 | Q7 | R7 | S7 | T7 | U7 | V7 | W7 | X7 | Y7 | Z7 |
| 8 | A8 | B8 | C8 | D8 | E8 | F8 | G8 | H8 | I8 | J8 | K8 | L8 | M8 | N8 | O8 | P8 | Q8 | R8 | S8 | T8 | U8 | V8 | W8 | X8 | Y8 | Z8 |
| 9 | A9 | B9 | C9 | D9 | E9 | F9 | G9 | H9 | I9 | J9 | K9 | L9 | M9 | N9 | O9 | P9 | Q9 | R9 | S9 | T9 | U9 | V9 | W9 | X9 | Y9 | Z9 |
| 10 | A10 | B10 | C10 | D10 | E10 | F10 | G10 | H10 | I10 | J10 | K10 | L10 | M10 | N10 | O10 | P10 | Q10 | R10 | S10 | T10 | U10 | V10 | W10 | X10 | Y10 | Z10 |
| 11 | A11 | B11 | C11 | D11 | E11 | F11 | G11 | H11 | I11 | J11 | K11 | L11 | M11 | N11 | O11 | P11 | Q11 | R11 | S11 | T11 | U11 | V11 | W11 | X11 | Y11 | Z11 |
| 12 | A12 | B12 | C12 | D12 | E12 | F12 | G12 | H12 | I12 | J12 | K12 | L12 | M12 | N12 | O12 | P12 | Q12 | R12 | S12 | T12 | U12 | V12 | W12 | X12 | Y12 | Z12 |
| 13 | A13 | B13 | C13 | D13 | E13 | F13 | G13 | H13 | I13 | J13 | K13 | L13 | M13 | N13 | O13 | P13 | Q13 | R13 | S13 | T13 | U13 | V13 | W13 | X13 | Y13 | Z13 |
| 14 | A14 | B14 | C14 | D14 | E14 | F14 | G14 | H14 | I14 | J14 | K14 | L14 | M14 | N14 | O14 | P14 | Q14 | R14 | S14 | T14 | U14 | V14 | W14 | X14 | Y14 | Z14 |
| 15 | A15 | B15 | C15 | D15 | E15 | F15 | G15 | H15 | I15 | J15 | K15 | L15 | M15 | N15 | O15 | P15 | Q15 | R15 | S15 | T15 | U15 | V15 | W15 | X15 | Y15 | Z15 |
| 16 | A16 | B16 | C16 | D16 | E16 | F16 | G16 | H16 | I16 | J16 | K16 | L16 | M16 | N16 | O16 | P16 | Q16 | R16 | S16 | T16 | U16 | V16 | W16 | X16 | Y16 | Z16 |
| 17 | A17 | B17 | C17 | D17 | E17 | F17 | G17 | H17 | I17 | J17 | K17 | L17 | M17 | N17 | O17 | P17 | Q17 | R17 | S17 | T17 | U17 | V17 | W17 | X17 | Y17 | Z17 |
| 18 | A18 | B18 | C18 | D18 | E18 | F18 | G18 | H18 | I18 | J18 | K18 | L18 | M18 | N18 | O18 | P18 | Q18 | R18 | S18 | T18 | U18 | V18 | W18 | X18 | Y18 | Z18 |
| 19 | A19 | B19 | C19 | D19 | E19 | F19 | G19 | H19 | I19 | J19 | K19 | L19 | M19 | N19 | O19 | P19 | Q19 | R19 | S19 | T19 | U19 | V19 | W19 | X19 | Y19 | Z19 |
| 20 | A20 | B20 | C20 | D20 | E20 | F20 | G20 | H20 | I20 | J20 | K20 | L20 | M20 | N20 | O20 | P20 | Q20 | R20 | S20 | T20 | U20 | V20 | W20 | X20 | Y20 | Z20 |
| 21 | A21 | B21 | C21 | D21 | E21 | F21 | G21 | H21 | I21 | J21 | K21 | L21 | M21 | N21 | O21 | P21 | Q21 | R21 | S21 | T21 | U21 | V21 | W21 | X21 | Y21 | Z21 |
| 22 | A22 | B22 | C22 | D22 | E22 | F22 | G22 | H22 | I22 | J22 | K22 | L22 | M22 | N22 | O22 | P22 | Q22 | R22 | S22 | T22 | U22 | V22 | W22 | X22 | Y22 | Z22 |
| 23 | A23 | B23 | C23 | D23 | E23 | F23 | G23 | H23 | I23 | J23 | K23 | L23 | M23 | N23 | O23 | P23 | Q23 | R23 | S23 | T23 | U23 | V23 | W23 | X23 | Y23 | Z23 |
| 24 | A24 | B24 | C24 | D24 | E24 | F24 | G24 | H24 | I24 | J24 | K24 | L24 | M24 | N24 | O24 | P24 | Q24 | R24 | S24 | T24 | U24 | V24 | W24 | X24 | Y24 | Z24 |
| 25 | A25 | B25 | C25 | D25 | E25 | F25 | G25 | H25 | I25 | J25 | K25 | L25 | M25 | N25 | O25 | P25 | Q25 | R25 | S25 | T25 | U25 | V25 | W25 | X25 | Y25 | Z25 |
| 26 | A26 | B26 | C26 | D26 | E26 | F26 | G26 | H26 | I26 | J26 | K26 | L26 | M26 | N26 | O26 | P26 | Q26 | R26 | S26 | T26 | U26 | V26 | W26 | X26 | Y26 | Z26 |

B5 == A5

Sheet1:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | COL1 | COL2 |
| 2 |  |  |
| 3 |  |  |
| 4 |  |  |
| 5 |  | A5 |
| 6 |  | B5 |
| 7 |  | B6 |
| 8 |  | B7 |
| 9 |  | B8 |
| 10 |  | B9 |
| 11 |  | B10 |
| 12 |  | B11 |
| 13 |  | B12 |
| 14 |  | B13 |
| 15 |  | B14 |
| 16 |  | B15 |
| 17 |  | B16 |
| 18 |  | B17 |
| 19 |  | B18 |
| 20 |  | B19 |
| 21 |  | B20 |

Comment: Can you apply this in my context? This is the spreadsheet im working with 
Link: "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T-XmQUHvE77hGcyZKIqqslypBjMs7eMGYlJ0TD1ooaY/edit#gid=0"
I would like to have the stack of 16 names from the tab 'hidden' apply to the range B6:B21 on tab '1st Set' if B5 from first set is equal to the team name displayed above the different list of names

Comment: I do not follow links to off site resources.  I would think that a programmer shoud be able to modify the code so that it could work in their particular situation. - [Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, or anyone who writes code because they love it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I am just new to using google sheets and Java script so I’m having difficulty understanding code written by others as I’m mostly learning as I go and encounter problems

Comment: Don't give up you'll figure it out. Here's an online resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript